# When `emacs` is started, use `emacsclient` instead if there is a server

Tags: emacsclient, server

Most modern editors don't have a separate `<editor>client` binary. Instead, the main binary acts as a client to open a new window/the file given as an argument when possible.

Is there a way to accomplish the same in Emacs? I know about `emacsclient` but 1. it's not a drop-in replacement and 2. using it comfortably requires additional setup beyond copying `.emacs.d` to a machine -- e.g. adding a desktop file for `emacsclient`.

I'm envisioning something like this:

```el
;; Start of init.el
(if (server-running-p)
    ;; Open given file in existing server
  (server-start))
```

Comment: related: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/47894/262

Comment: Unclear why you would want a desktop file for `emacsclient` if you've already opened emacs.  Do you perhaps just want to [open a new frame](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Creating-Frames.html)?  If so, you can do so from any existing emacs frame with `make-frame-command`, bound by default to `C-x 5 2`.

Comment: @Dan I don't want a desktop file for `emacsclient`. That's an example of what I want to avoid. I want `emacs`, the main binary, to act as a client to open a new window/the file given as an argument when possible.

Answer (score 4):

Nowadays several megabytes are no problem for a client program.
So maybe [the problem of the size of Emacs](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/47894/2370) is no longer that relevant.

With Emacs 27 you can run stuff in `~/.emacs.d/early-init.el` before the initial frame opens.
There you can try:

```el
(require 'server)
(if (server-running-p "server")
  (let ((file-name (expand-file-name (car (cdr command-line-args)))))
    (unwind-protect
        (server-eval-at "server" `(find-file ,file-name))
      (kill-emacs)))
  (message "Server not running."))
(server-start)
```

If you run `emacs somefile` when the Emacs server is already running `somefile` should be opened in the server.

This is just a proof of principle. The handling of the argument is very rudimentary. One has to refine the argument handling if one wants to use that principle for production.

I only have `emacs26` on my machine. Therefore, I cannot test the `early-init.el`-approach. 
If I put the above code into `~/.emacs` it opens the file given on the command line in the already running server but the client opens an initial frame before it runs the code. So there is some kind of flicker.

Answer (score 1):

The `alternative-editor` option supports this. The following invocation does what you describe:

```
emacsclient -a""
```

This opens emacsclient, and starts the server if it isn't already running.

See the manual for details: https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Invoking-emacsclient.html

Comment: I want `emacs` to open `emacsclient`, not the other way round.

Comment: if the actual name you use to start the program is critical, you could just define an alias to map emacs to emacsclient -a""

Comment: That's additional setup outside Emacs, the very thing I'm trying to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work for you? You can save it as a script in `PATH` and run it instead of `emacs` or `emacsclient`.

```
#!/bin/bash

export REAL_EMACS_START=1
emacsclient $@ || emacs $@
```

**EDIT**:

If you want user to run `emacs` directly and achieve similar result, you can add the following to the top of `init.el`:

```
(unless (getenv "REAL_EMACS_START")
  (call-process-shell-command
   (format "export REAL_EMACS_START=1; (%sclient || %s) &" invocation-name invocation-name))
  (kill-emacs))
```

Comment: No. That's additional setup beyond copying .emacs.d to a machine.

Comment: @Erik Please see my edit